# How can I insert a barcode into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, barcode

I'm trying to insert a barcode image into database using AxBarCodeWiz, it's a tool that generates barcode and is displayed as a picturebox and I can edit the barcode using its built in property.

My problem is when I try to insert the barcode into database I get this error saying "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". I thought it's because i'm using a wrong datatype in my database so I changed its datatype to BLOB but the still error also tried CHAR but still the same error.

This is the code I use to insert values into database if it is important

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim insertbarcode As String = "INSERT INTO eeldatabase.barcode(Barcode, ItemCode, Operation, BundleNumber, Color, Size, Quantity, Price, Amount) values( '" & AxBarCodeWiz3.Barcode & "', '" & txtItemCode.Text & "', '" & txtOperation.Text & "', '" & txtBundleNo.Text & "', '" & txtColor.Text & "', '" & txtSize.Text & "' '" & txtQuantity.Text & "', '" & txtPrice.Text & "', '" & txtAmount.Text & "')"
    Dim answer As Integer

    If txtItemCode.Text = "" Or txtOperation.Text = "" Or txtBundleNo.Text = "" Or txtColor.Text = "" Or txtSize.Text = "" Or txtQuantity.Text = "" Or txtPrice.Text = "" Or txtAmount.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields!", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Else

        answer = MsgBox("Add this Barcode to the database?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Barcode")

        If answer = vbYes Then


            ExecuteQuery(insertbarcode)
            MessageBox.Show("Barcode successfuly added!")
            connection.Close()
            connection.Dispose()



            txtItemCode.Text = ""
            txtOperation.Text = ""
            txtBundleNo.Text = ""
            txtColor.Text = ""
            txtSize.Text = ""
            txtQuantity.Text = ""
            txtPrice.Text = ""
            txtAmount.Text = ""

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Barcode not inserted")

            txtItemCode.Text = ""
            txtOperation.Text = ""
            txtBundleNo.Text = ""
            txtColor.Text = ""
            txtSize.Text = ""
            txtQuantity.Text = ""
            txtPrice.Text = ""
            txtAmount.Text = ""

        End If

        connection.Close()

        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM eeldatabase.barcode", connection)

        adapter.Fill(table)

        dgvBarcode.DataSource = table

    End If

End Sub
```

Is it possible to insert this barcode to my database or is it not? If not can I just use its text value to be inserted in the database because the main purpose of this is for the user to be able to scan a barcode and retrieve that barcode that is saved in the database so even a text value would be okay to use.

Comment: Use use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code.  ALWAYS use parameters.  Learn how to do that first and then see whether you still have an issue.

Comment: What data type is that `AxBarCodeWiz3.Barcode` properrty?

Comment: I was trying things the first one i used was AxBarCodeWiz3.Text has no error in design time but does not work then i tried that AxBarCodeWiz3.Barcode also no error in design but still doesn't work.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.  That said, a barcode is basically just a representation of a character string that can be easily read by an optical instrument.  It would be rare that you would want that representation stored in a database.  Rather, you would want the actual character string.  I would guess that you would get that from the `Text` property of your control.  You should confirm that by reading documentation and testing.  In that case, your database column should be a text data type, e.g. `varchar`. You should still be using parameters regardless.

Comment: Varchar and text property won't work because the control is like a picturebox control and I edit it using a button that shows its built in property, in the property I can change the characters and barcode type to be displayed in the picturebox control.

Comment: IDK why you need to store barcode picture in DB? Store just text representation of barcode, and on the client side, you would generate barcode from this text representation

Comment: @Everyone The `.Barcode` property is the text representation.

Comment: @KinoFilme The correct way, which will work, is to use SQL parameters as jmcilhinney commented earlier. The error message you're seeing is due to a `"' '"` instead of a `"', '"`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for that , i should probably be looking for how to use parameters. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @PeterKsenak im trying to store barcode picture for printing purposes, like if im done inserting 20 barcodes into database i'll be able to print those 20 barcodes (just the pictures) and be used for scanning. What I'm trying to achieve is generate barcode > insert to database > print barcodes(pictures) > distribute actual barcodes > and when the barcodes comeback to the user, the user will scan those barcodes that will represent as reports so the 20 barcodes saved to database must be the only barcodes that will be accepted by the application.

Comment: Holy Sql Injection vulnerability, Batman!